Trouble with branch cuts plotting a real function
When I plot the following function
f[x_] := 
  1/ (x^2) (-2  (-2 + Sqrt[((1 - I) + x^2)^2] + Sqrt[((1 + I) + x^2)^2]) + x (2  Sqrt[(4 - 4  I) + x^2]  (-Log[-(x/((4 - 4  I) + x^2)^(3/2)) +  1/((4 - 4  I) + x^2)] +  Log[((1 + I)  ((3 - 3  I)  x + x^3 +  Sqrt[((1 - I) + x^2)^2] Sqrt[(4 - 4  I) + x^2]))/((4 -  4  I) + x^2)^(3/2)]) +   2  Sqrt[(4 + 4  I) + x^2]  (-Log[-(x/((4 + 4  I) + x^2)^(3/2)) +   1/((4 + 4  I) + x^2)] +  Log[((1 - I)  ((3 + 3  I)  x + x^3 +  Sqrt[((1 + I) + x^2)^2] Sqrt[(4 + 4  I) + x^2]))/((4 +  4  I) + x^2)^(3/2)])));

Mathematica has no problem, it gives the correct result (which is real, and Mathematica does it well).
The issue comes when I want to plot the function f[I*x], with the imaginary number I in the argument. In this case, the code is simply
Plot[Re[f[I*x]], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]

but it has a nonzero imaginary part. This would not be a terrible problem, but the real part suffers from branch cuts, which correspond to the "unjoined" plot showing below:
How can I tell Mathematica to give the "correct" plot with the parts "joined"? I mean, obtaining the smooth draw of the function f[I*x]?

No chance in view of FunctionContinuous[{ComplexExpand[Re[f[I*x]]], x > 0}, x] which results in False.

Also look at the result of ComplexPlot3D[Re[f[I*z]], {z, 5}, PlotPoints -> 100].

@Axionlike particles:  I suspect by "smooth draw" you mean an analytically-continuous route through the various multi-function components of $f(x)$.   May be able to  isolate each multifuntion and stitch together a continuous route.
For example let $$g(x)=\sqrt{\left(x^2+(1+i)\right)^2}$$.  Then continuous route of  $g(i x)$  over $0<x<2$  is done with Re@g(ix) in interval (0,1) and Re@(-g(ix)) in (1,2).   Try plotting both and then Show[{g1plot,g2plo2)]  and you'll see what I mean.

Sorry for the sloppy language, by "smooth draw" I was precisely meaning what @josh said, this is, obtain a "continuous" function by joining/gluing the multifunction components of the whole function. Josh example is great, and after plotting it that is exactly what I want, although I don't know how to do it for the more difficult OP case with Sqrts and Logs.

@Axionlike particles:  Next look at $h(x)=\sqrt{x^2+(4+4 i)}$ for $h(ix)$ in interval $0<x<5$.  How can you continuously splice that one?  Then how to splice product $\sqrt{\left(x^2+(1+i)\right)^2} \sqrt{x^2+(4+4 i)}$?  Easier to select them if you first select your expression and then Cell/Convert To/Traditional Form.

@josh, Yeah, I got it. The thing is my expression was a bit longer that what I wrote above, but I think there's no other way than do it step by step and plot several products of the different multifunction choosing all the time the correct branch. Thank you!

@Axionlike:  If you like DEs, You can do it differentially by solving IVP via NDSolve.  Note $$\frac{dg}{dt}=\frac{2x(1+i+x^2)}{g} i,\quad x(t)=it$$.  Then ndsolve for $0<t<5$.  Solution is analytically continuous over $g(x)$.  Do that with all of them, then substitute all the individual solutions into your expression, then plot $0<t<5$.  Should work but will be a challenge :).

Your question is unclear to me: "the smooth draw of the function f[I*x]" is impossible.

Note:  I made a mistake with a parentheses in definition of newF[t] in the approved  version of this thread and don't want to edit that version.  I added the new version of the code below the old version with a note about correction as well as a check that contours $x(t)=it$ and $x(t)=3/2e^{it}$ are passing over some of the branch surfaces of a ParametricPlot3D plot of $f(z)$.
Will express each root and log with an analytically-continuous version over the domain $0\leq x\leq 5$ and with $x=it$ by solving the associated IVP.  In the code below, the radicals are replaced by their algebraic form.  For example $s1(x)=(x^2+4+4i)^{3/2}$ is expressed as $f(x,w)=(x^2+4+4i)^3-w^2=0$.  This way can express the radical as a solution to the IVP
$$
\frac{dw}{dt}=-\frac{f_x}{f_w}\frac{dx}{dt},\quad w_0=s1(x(0)),\quad x(0)=0
$$
There are six different radicals, the continuous versions of which are sXFSol(t) with X ranging from 1 to 6, and four log solutions logXSol with X ranging from 1 to 4.
I created getContinuousSolution to return the IVP solution for the radicals, and getLogSolution for the log solutions.  The log IVPs have as their initial conditions, the necessary sXFSol expressions.
Thuse, an analytically-continuous version of $f(x)$ for $x=it$ in interval $0\leq t \leq 5$ can be expressed as:
newF[t_] := 1/x^2 (x (2 s2FSol[t] (log1F[t] - log2F[t]) + 
         2 s5FSol[t] (log3F[t] - log4F[t])) - 2 (s4FSol[t] + 
         s1FSol[t]) - 2) /. x -> I t;

Keep in mind $f(z)$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$ is infinitely-valued, so my solution may not agree with others, depending on which function sheet the contour begins on.
(* define radicals and algebraic forms *)
 s1[x_] := \!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*SqrtBox[
SuperscriptBox[\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + \((1 + I)\))\), \(2\)]]\);
s1F[x_, w_] := (x^2 + 1 + I)^2 - w^2;

s2[x_] := \!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*SqrtBox[\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + \((4 + 4\ I)\)\)]\);
s2F[x_, w_] := x^2 + 4 + 4 I - w^2;

s3[x_] := \!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*SuperscriptBox[\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + \((4 + 4\ I)\))\), \(3/2\)]\);
s3F[x_, w_] := (x^2 + 4 + 4 I)^3 - w^2;

s4[x_] := \!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*SqrtBox[
SuperscriptBox[\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + \((1 - I)\))\), \(2\)]]\);
s4F[x_, w_] := (x^2 + 1 - I)^2 - w^2;

s5[x_] := \!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*SqrtBox[\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + \((4 - 4\ I)\)\)]\);
s5F[x_, w_] := x^2 + 4 - 4 I - w^2;

s6[x_] := \!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*SuperscriptBox[\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + \((4 - 4\ I)\))\), \(3/2\)]\);
s6F[x_, w_] := (x^2 + 4 - 4 I)^3 - w^2;
(*
 Construct radical and log IVP functions
*)

getContinuousSol[s1_, s1F_, theX_, tStart_, tEnd_, rIndex_] := 
  Module[{sFDeriv, sFRoots, sFSol},
   sFDeriv = 
    w'[t] == ((-(D[s1F[x, w], x]/D[s1F[x, w], w]) (D[theX[t], 
           t ])) /. {w -> w[t], x -> theX[t]});
   sFRoots = w /. NSolve[s1F[0, w] == 0, w];
   sFSol = 
    NDSolveValue[{sFDeriv, w[tStart] == sFRoots[[rIndex]]}, 
     w, {t, tStart, tEnd}];
   sFSol
   ];
 getContinuousLog[theX_] := Module[{lDeriv, logFSol},
   lDeriv = w'[t] == (1/z D[theX[t], t]) /. {z -> theX[t]};
   logFSol = NDSolveValue[{lDeriv, w[0] == Log[theX[0]]}, w, {t, 0, 5}]
   ];
(*
 solve for the radical IVPs
*)
tStart = 0;
tEnd = 5;

theX[t_] := I t;
s1FSol = getContinuousSol[s1, s1F, theX, 0, 5, 1];
(*ReImPlot[s1FSol[t],{t,0,5}]*)

s2FSol = getContinuousSol[s2, s2F, theX, 0, 5, 1];
(*ReImPlot[s2FSol[t],{t,0,5}]
*)
s3FSol = getContinuousSol[s3, s3F, theX, 0, 5, 1];
(*ReImPlot[s3FSol[t],{t,0,5}]
*)
s4FSol = getContinuousSol[s4, s4F, theX, 0, 5, 1];
(*ReImPlot[s4FSol[t],{t,0,5}]
*)
s5FSol = getContinuousSol[s5, s5F, theX, 0, 5, 1];
(*ReImPlot[s5FSol[t],{t,0,5}]*)

s6FSol = getContinuousSol[s6, s6F, theX, 0, 5, 1];
(*ReImPlot[s6FSol[t],{t,0,5}]
*)
(*
 solve for the log expressions
*)
(*
 do log1F
*)
theX[t_] := ((1 - I) (x^3 + s1FSol[t] s2FSol[t] + (3 + 3 I) x))/
   s3FSol[t] /. x -> I t;
log1F = getContinuousLog[theX];
(*ReImPlot[log1F[t],{t,tStart,tEnd}]*)
(*
 do log2F
*)
theX[t_] := (1/(x^2 + 4 + 4 I) - x/s3FSol[t]) /. x -> I t;
log2F = getContinuousLog[theX];
(*ReImPlot[log2F[t],{t,tStart,tEnd}]*)
(*
 do log3F
*)
theX[t_] := ((1 + I) (x^3 + s4FSol[t] s5FSol[t] + (3 - 3 I) x))/
   s6FSol[t] /. x -> I t;
log3F = getContinuousLog[theX];
(*ReImPlot[log3F[t],{t,tStart,tEnd}]*)
(*
 do log4F 
*)
theX[t_] := (1/(x^2 + 4 - 4 I) - x/s6FSol[t]) /. x -> I t;
log4F = getContinuousLog[theX];
(*ReImPlot[log4F[t],{t,tStart,tEnd}]*)
(*
 construct analytically-continuously version of f(it)
*)
newF[t_] := 
  1/x^2 (x (2 s2FSol[t] (log1F[t] - log2F[t]) + 
         2 s5FSol[t] (log3F[t] - log4F[t])) - 
      2 (s4FSol[t] + s1FSol[t]) - 2) /. x -> I t;

f[x_] := 
  1/(x^2) (-2 (-2 + Sqrt[((1 - I) + x^2)^2] + 
        Sqrt[((1 + I) + x^2)^2]) + 
     x (2 Sqrt[(4 - 4 I) + 
           x^2] (-Log[-(x/((4 - 4 I) + x^2)^(3/2)) + 
              1/((4 - 4 I) + x^2)] + 
           Log[((1 + I) ((3 - 3 I) x + x^3 + 
                 Sqrt[((1 - I) + x^2)^2] Sqrt[(4 - 4 I) + 
                    x^2]))/((4 - 4 I) + x^2)^(3/2)]) + 
        2 Sqrt[(4 + 4 I) + 
           x^2] (-Log[-(x/((4 + 4 I) + x^2)^(3/2)) + 
              1/((4 + 4 I) + x^2)] + 
           Log[((1 - I) ((3 + 3 I) x + x^3 + 
                 Sqrt[((1 + I) + x^2)^2] Sqrt[(4 + 4 I) + 
                    x^2]))/((4 + 4 I) + x^2)^(3/2)])));

realPlot = 
  Plot[{Re@newF[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-30, 30}}];
imagPlot = 
  Plot[{Im@newF[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-30, 30}}];
reimPlot = ReImPlot[f[I t], {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Gray];

Show[{realPlot, imagPlot, reimPlot}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Column[{"Analytically-continuous route through f(x)", 
    "Blue: real part, Red: imag part", "Gray is original f(x)"}, 
   Alignment -> Center]]

Edit:  Version of newF(t) with correct placement of parenthesis and a check of contours over ParametricPlot3D of f(x)
(* define radicals and algebraic forms *)
 s1[x_] := \!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*SqrtBox[
SuperscriptBox[\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + \((1 + I)\))\), \(2\)]]\);
s1F[x_, w_] := (x^2 + 1 + I)^2 - w^2;

s2[x_] := \!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*SqrtBox[\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + \((4 + 4\ I)\)\)]\);
s2F[x_, w_] := x^2 + 4 + 4 I - w^2;

s3[x_] := \!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*SuperscriptBox[\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + \((4 + 4\ I)\))\), \(3/2\)]\);
s3F[x_, w_] := (x^2 + 4 + 4 I)^3 - w^2;

s4[x_] := \!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*SqrtBox[
SuperscriptBox[\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + \((1 - I)\))\), \(2\)]]\);
s4F[x_, w_] := (x^2 + 1 - I)^2 - w^2;

s5[x_] := \!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*SqrtBox[\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + \((4 - 4\ I)\)\)]\);
s5F[x_, w_] := x^2 + 4 - 4 I - w^2;

s6[x_] := \!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*SuperscriptBox[\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] + \((4 - 4\ I)\))\), \(3/2\)]\);
s6F[x_, w_] := (x^2 + 4 - 4 I)^3 - w^2;
(*
 Construct radical and log IVP functions
*)

getContinuousSol[s1_, s1F_, theX_, tStart_, tEnd_, rIndex_] := 
  Module[{sFDeriv, sFRoots, sFSol, w, t, sFRoot, x},
   sFDeriv = 
    w'[t] == ((-(D[s1F[x, w], x]/D[s1F[x, w], w]) (D[theX[t], 
           t ])) /. {w -> w[t], x -> theX[t]});
   sFRoots = w /. NSolve[s1F[theX[tStart], w] == 0, w];
   (*sFRoot=s1[theX[tStart]];*)
   sFSol = 
    NDSolveValue[{sFDeriv, w[tStart] == sFRoots[[2]]}, 
     w, {t, tStart, tEnd}];
   sFSol
   ];
 getContinuousLog[theX_, tStart_, tEnd_] := 
  Module[{lDeriv, logFSol, w, t, z},
   lDeriv = w'[t] == (1/z D[theX[t], t]) /. {z -> theX[t]};
   logFSol = 
    NDSolveValue[{lDeriv, w[tStart] == Log[theX[tStart]]}, 
     w, {t, tStart, tEnd}]
   ];
(*
 solve for the radical IVPs
*)
tStart = 0;
tEnd = 5;
theX[t_] := I t;

s1FSol = getContinuousSol[s1, s1F, theX, tStart, tEnd, 1];
(*ReImPlot[s1FSol[t],{t,tStart,tEnd}]*)

s2FSol = getContinuousSol[s2, s2F, theX, tStart, tEnd, 1];
(*ReImPlot[s2FSol[t],{t,0,5}]*)

s3FSol = getContinuousSol[s3, s3F, theX, tStart, tEnd, 1];
(*ReImPlot[s3FSol[t],{t,0,5}]*)

s4FSol = getContinuousSol[s4, s4F, theX, tStart, tEnd, 1];
(*ReImPlot[s4FSol[t],{t,0,5}]*)

s5FSol = getContinuousSol[s5, s5F, theX, tStart, tEnd, 1];
(*ReImPlot[s5FSol[t],{t,0,5}]*)

s6FSol = getContinuousSol[s6, s6F, theX, tStart, tEnd, 1];
(*ReImPlot[s6FSol[t],{t,0,5}]
*)
(*
 solve for the log expressions
*)
(*
 do log1F
*)
theArg[t_] := ((1 - I) (x^3 + s1FSol[t] s2FSol[t] + (3 + 3 I) x))/
   s3FSol[t] /. x -> theX[t];
log1F = getContinuousLog[theArg, tStart, tEnd];
(*ReImPlot[log1F[t],{t,tStart,tEnd}]*)
(*
 do log2F
*)
theArg[t_] := (1/(x^2 + 4 + 4 I) - x/s3FSol[t]) /. x -> theX[t];
log2F = getContinuousLog[theArg, tStart, tEnd];
(*ReImPlot[log2F[t],{t,tStart,tEnd}]*)
(*
 do log3F
*)
theArg[t_] := ((1 + I) (x^3 + s4FSol[t] s5FSol[t] + (3 - 3 I) x))/
   s6FSol[t] /. x -> theX[t];
log3F = getContinuousLog[theArg, tStart, tEnd];
(*ReImPlot[log3F[t],{t,tStart,tEnd}]*)
(*
 do log4F 
*)
theArg[t_] := (1/(x^2 + 4 - 4 I) - x/s6FSol[t]) /. x -> theX[t];
log4F = getContinuousLog[theArg, tStart, tEnd];
(*ReImPlot[log4F[t],{t,tStart,tEnd}]*)
(*
 construct analytically-continuously version of f(it)
*)
 newF[t_] := 
  1/x^2 (x (2 s2FSol[t] (log1F[t] - log2F[t]) + 
         2 s5FSol[t] (log3F[t] - log4F[t])) - 
      2 (s4FSol[t] + s1FSol[t] - 2)) /. x -> theX[t];

f[x_] := 
  1/(x^2) (-2 (-2 + Sqrt[((1 - I) + x^2)^2] + 
        Sqrt[((1 + I) + x^2)^2]) + 
     x (2 Sqrt[(4 - 4 I) + 
           x^2] (-Log[-(x/((4 - 4 I) + x^2)^(3/2)) + 
              1/((4 - 4 I) + x^2)] + 
           Log[((1 + I) ((3 - 3 I) x + x^3 + 
                 Sqrt[((1 - I) + x^2)^2] Sqrt[(4 - 4 I) + 
                    x^2]))/((4 - 4 I) + x^2)^(3/2)]) + 
        2 Sqrt[(4 + 4 I) + 
           x^2] (-Log[-(x/((4 + 4 I) + x^2)^(3/2)) + 
              1/((4 + 4 I) + x^2)] + 
           Log[((1 - I) ((3 + 3 I) x + x^3 + 
                 Sqrt[((1 + I) + x^2)^2] Sqrt[(4 + 4 I) + 
                    x^2]))/((4 + 4 I) + x^2)^(3/2)])));
(*
 check continuation file over plot of f(x).  Should pass over at \
least some of the branch-cut surfaces
*)
pp1 = ParametricPlot3D[{Re@theX[t], Im@theX[t], Re@newF[t]}, {t, 
    tStart, tEnd}, PlotStyle -> Red, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}];
pRange = PlotRange[pp1]
pp2 = ParametricPlot3D[{Re@z, Im@z, Re@f[z]} /. z -> r Exp[I t], {r, 
    0.001, 2}, {t, -Pi, Pi},
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50];
pRange = PlotRange[pp2];
startPointG = 
  Graphics3D@{PointSize[0.05], Red, Point@{0, 0, Re@newF[0.01]}};
plot1 = Show[{pp2, pp1(*,startPointG*)}, PlotRange -> pRange, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style["Re[z]", 12, Black, Bold], 
    Style["Im[z]", 12, Black, Bold], Style["Re@f", 12, Black, Bold]}, 
  PlotLabel -> "x(t)=3/2 Exp[i t] contour for -Pi<t<Pi"]




This was working very well, but in fact for the last logs I have in my function the values w0 are indeterminate! I don't know how to handle that

I updated my code with a functional form.  Easier to read.  Best I think to just replace my post with it.  Hope it helps.

Is there a way to choose the contour so that the smooth function coincide with original function around x=0?

@azerbajdzan:  Mathematica gives $$\lim_{t->0^+}f(it)=-i\infty$$.  Appears reasonable since have $1/x^2$ factor. Also f(0.00001i) has real part $12$ but f(0) is indeterminate.  Not sure how to make smooth funtion coincide with original funtion a bit away from 0 like f(0.25).  Will look into it.

@josh Accepting your answer, I think it is the most robust approach. The issue with 0 is interesting, I was aware of it too.

@Axionlke particles:  Not sure I have this correct.  When I do a ParametricPlot3D of the real parts of your f(z) in complex space,  and my newF[t], my solution does not agree with any surface of the (highly branch-cut) 3D plot.  I would expect at least some of it to agree.  I'll look into it more and see if I can resolve this.

@josh The original function has a pole in imaginary part when x->0. That is the way it is. The pole can not be removed for that branch.

@Axion particles:  I made a mistake with a parenthesis with version you accepted, and now sure I should correct it after acceptance so I added the new version below the old version as well as two  plots showing the contours $x(t)=it$ and $x(t)=3/2 e^{it}$ are indeed traversing some of the sheets of a ParametricPlot3D of $f(z)$ and for me demonstrating the IVPs are likely correct.

One can differentiate and then integrate the function. Integration yields a continuous function.
Clear[df]
df[x_] = f'[x];
a = 0.01;
fa = Limit[Re[f[I*x]], x -> a, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
h = NDSolveValue[{g'[x] == Re[I*df[I*x]], g[a] == fa}, g, {x, a, 5}]

Note that $a$ is set to a small positive value to avoid numerical issues at $x=0$. Now we can plot and compare to the original
Plot[{h[x], Re[f[I*x]]}, {x, a, 5}, PlotRange -> All]


I would like to remark that original post is not well formulated. For instance this is how the function looks like in complex plane

and this is how @azerbajdzan function looks like

When should specify the desired analytic properties.

The question is not about gluing unrelated branches together to form a continuous function that is not smooth. The question is about making a smooth analytical function by choosing branches that fit together smoothly.

@azerbajdzan Probably you are right, and I like your solution. But the OP is not clearly written.

You probably ComplexPlot-ed f[x] not f[I x]. OP wants analytical function for real x. As can be seen from ComplexPlot of my f2[x] it is analytical on real x axes, i.e. no branch cut  is crossing x axes (except for the origin which is natural and can not be removed). But  f[I x] branch cuts cross x axes multiple times.

@azerbajdzan Yes, you are right about that. My goal was to show the overall complicated structure.

Update:
In fact no Piecewise is needed.
f2[x_] := -4 + 
  2 (Sqrt[(-4 - 4 I)/x^2 + 1] - Sqrt[(-4 + 4 I)/x^2 + 1]) (I Pi + 
     Log[8]) - 
  2 Sqrt[(-4 - 4 I)/x^2 + 
     1] Log[-4 + ((2 + 2 I) - x^2) Sqrt[(4 + 4 I) x^2 - x^4] + 
     I x^2 ((-4 - 4 I) + x^2)] + 
  2 Sqrt[(-4 + 4 I)/x^2 + 
     1] Log[-4 + ((-2 + 2 I) + x^2) Sqrt[(4 - 4 I) x^2 - x^4] + 
     I x^2 ((4 - 4 I) - x^2)]

ReImPlot[f2[x], {x, -10, 10}]



ReImPlot[{f[I x], f2[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.006], Automatic}]



Original answer:
Solid blue is Re of original function and dashed blue is Im of original function.
Orange plot depicts continuous function both for Re and Im. It was done mainly by hand but with a help of Mathematica. Making it automatic seems to be a big task.
ReImPlot[{f[x I], 
  1/x 2 (-2 x + 
     Sqrt[x^2 - (4 - 
         4 I)] (Piecewise[{{Log[
            1/2 + x/8 ((2 - 2 I) - x^2) Sqrt[(4 - 4 I) - x^2] - 
             1/8 I x^2 ((4 - 4 I) - x^2)] + 2 Pi I, 
          x < -2}, {Log[
           1/2 + x/8 ((2 - 2 I) - x^2) Sqrt[(4 - 4 I) - x^2] - 
            1/8 I x^2 ((4 - 4 I) - x^2)], -2 <= x <= 
           2}, {Log[
            1/2 + x/8 ((2 - 2 I) - x^2) Sqrt[(4 - 4 I) - x^2] - 
             1/8 I x^2 ((4 - 4 I) - x^2)] - 2 Pi I, x > 2}}]) - 
     Sqrt[x^2 - (4 + 
         4 I)] (Piecewise[{{Log[
            1/2 + x/8 ((-2 - 2 I) + x^2) Sqrt[(4 + 4 I) - x^2] + 
             1/8 I x^2 ((4 + 4 I) - x^2)] + 2 Pi I, 
          x < -2}, {Log[
           1/2 + x/8 ((-2 - 2 I) + x^2) Sqrt[(4 + 4 I) - x^2] + 
            1/8 I x^2 ((4 + 4 I) - x^2)], -2 <= x <= 
           2}, {Log[
            1/2 + x/8 ((-2 - 2 I) + x^2) Sqrt[(4 + 4 I) - x^2] + 
             1/8 I x^2 ((4 + 4 I) - x^2)] - 2 Pi I, x > 2}}]))}, {x, 
  0, 5}, ReImStyle -> {{Thickness[.007], 
    Directive[Thickness[.007], Dashed]}, {Thick, 
    Directive[Thick, Dashed]}}]




Can you kindly explain how your piece-wise function is obtained from the OP's f[I*x] for x > 1?

@user64494 By inspecting each Sqrt and Log of original function. Since they are multifunctions I choose at each discontinuity the branch cuts that made the function continuous/smooth. You can see in Piecewise that +2 Pi I or -2 Pi I was added to the logarithm which is a way of choosing desired branch cut for logarithms. In general 2 k Pi I for some integer k.

Sorry, I don't see the common multiplier (-2 x + Sqrt[x^2 - (4 - 4 I) in f[I*x].

By the way, I copy-pasted your the code in the first box in a fresh notebook and did not get the same graph. Can you check.

@yarchik I have no idea what went wrong. When I simply copy and paste the code is somehow corrupted. I now used Copy as plaintext and it should work now.

I like your solution but I don't know how did you obtained it, it seems like you are choosing by hand the correct branch. Could we chat? @azerbajdzan

@Axionlikeparticles I do not know how to automatize the process. My intention was to show that for your function f[x I] there indeed exist a definition that is smooth on the whole real axis. I did it mainly by trial and error choosing different definitions for logarithms and square roots to move branch cuts out of x axis. But josh's answer seems to be reasonable for a methodic approach.
