Contour plot after numerical integration involving branch cut
I want to evaluate integrals of complicated functions with square root branch cuts and plot the contours of vanishing imaginary part. The simplest example is the following
Q[x_] := x;
s[X_] := Integrate[Sqrt[Q[x]], {x, 0, X}];
ComplexContourPlot[Im[s[x]] == 0, {x, -2 - 2 I , 2 + 2 I}]

It returns the correct plot:

However, f[x] could be very complicated which makes taking the integral analytically time consuming, if not impossible. Also, in some cases, there are additional variables, which complicates the integral more. So, I have to treat it numerically, so I use Nintegrate. It works fine except around the branch cut (along the negative real axis).
f[x_] := x;
sNum[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Sqrt[f[y]], {y, 0, x}];
ComplexContourPlot[Im[sNum[x]] == 0, {x, -2 - I , 2 + I}]


Any comment on the why this is the case and any suggestion to overcome this problem is welcome. Thanks!

What is the point of doubling the definition with ssNum[x_?NumericQ] := Evaluate[sNum[x]]?

Thank you for the notice. Evaluate was needed for my original problem to do some manipulations. Here it was redundant. I removed those parts. It has no relation with the original problem though.

Increasing PlotPoints improves things. Compare ComplexContourPlot[  Im[sNum[x]] == 0, {x, 0.0001 (-2 - I), 0.0001 (2 + I)}] and ComplexContourPlot[  Im[sNum[x]] == 0, {x, 0.0001 (-2 - I), 0.0001 (2 + I)},   PlotPoints -> 50]

I'm sorry, I think there is a misunderstanding. As far as I see, increasing PlotPoints is about accuracy of the lines. But here the problem is existence of the line on the negative real axis. It shouldn't be there at all.

@detre:  Branch cuts are problematic when relying on Mathematica's default cuts especially if the function is complicated or composite.  You may wish to consider creating analytically-continuous contours through your functions as per this link:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/308345/trouble-with-branch-cuts-plotting-a-real-function/308362?noredirect=1#comment755858_308362

As far as I know Mathematica does not have a function for identification of branch cuts.
What can be done is to use RegionFunction to remove unwanted regions but it assumes you know positions of branch cuts.
For your example it can be done the following way using threshold 0.01.
If you provide a more complicated example I may try to do the same with it.
f[x_] := x;
sNum[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Sqrt[f[y]], {y, 0, x}];

ComplexContourPlot[Im[sNum[x]] == 0, {x, -2 - I, 2 + I}, 
 RegionFunction -> (Abs@Im[#1] > 0.01 || Re[#1] > 0 &)]




Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
